# Miller's Theorem Application

Tags: cmos, stability

Miller's Theorem for a capacitor can be written as follows:
[image]

In the book 'Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits' by Behzad Razavi, I read the following:
[image]

**How does the author say that the capacitance at node E will be (1+Av2)Cc, shouldn't it be (1-Av2)Cc?**

Comment: Yes it is. I voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether \$A_{V_{2}}\$ is considered negative or positive. I have seen the assumption either way. The problem here is that the treatment is inconsistent. The Miller theorem expects a negative gain which is often expressed as -A thus "assuming" A is positive. To make that clear it should be written as -|A|.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the author say that the capacitance at node E will be (1+Av2)Cc, shouldn't it be (1-Av2)Cc?

You are correct. I guess what happens here is that `Av1` and `Av2` are negative numbers (because the figure represents a two-stage op-amp), so `1-Av2` would be the same as `1+|Av2|`. Perhaps the author is used to thinking of the gain magnitude here.