# Pole Splitting - Why does output pole not also decrease to lower frequency?

Tags: analog, pole-zeroplot

[Miller's Theorem Application](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/640094/millers-theorem-application/640113#640113)

This is a follow-on question.

I have a question regarding pole Splitting. If there was an existing capacitor on node E and on node A, I often see that books say that by adding a Miller cap, the pole at node E will decrease and the pole at node A will increase.

I understand why E decreases, but why does A increase? Node A will also see a higher capacitance than before.

Comment: What do you mean by pole? Like a filter/laplace pole?

Comment: @VoltageSpike yes. Frequency pole. Like the inverse of the R and C on any node

Comment: @AlfroJang80 Have you read [this web page](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/pole-splitting-and-miller-frequency-compensation/) on the topic, yet?

Answer (score 1):

The output pole is (originally; without feedback) basically 1/(2.π.ROUT*COUT). Because of the feedback given by the output capacitor, the effective output impedance of the amplifier is *reduced* by the feedback factor (from the feedback capacitor and the input capacitance). This lowering in output impedance effectively *raises* the pole formed by the output capacitor.

A very good explanation is at https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/ee/ee214/ee214.1042/Handouts/HO9POLESPLIt.pdf

Comment: that website is Access forbidden.